# How to supply a different implementation if the class implements an interface using Laravel's container

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, guzzle

I’m using dependency injection to inject instances of Guzzle’s HTTP client. I have several data provider classes that call external services, some of which needs to be routed through proxies. I have an empty interface `ConnectViaProxy` that is implemented on those classes. I want to bind a Guzzle instance with the proxy option set, but I can’t use:

```
$this->app->when(ConnectViaProxy::class)
    ->needs(GuzzleClient::class)
    ->give(function (): ProxiedGuzzle {
        return new ProxiedGuzzle();
    });
```

Because `when` requires a concrete class, not an interface.

Here is an example of a provider that should be proxied:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class FooProvider implements Provider, ConnectViaProxy
{
    public function __construct(GuzzleClient $client)
    {
        // Should be an instance of ProxiedGuzzle
        dd($client);
    }
}
```

And an example of a provider that shouldn't be proxied:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class BarProvider implements Provider
{
    public function __construct(GuzzleClient $client)
    {
        // Should be an instance of GuzzleClient
        dd($client);
    }
}
```

And here is the `ProxiedGuzzle` class:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;

class ProxiedGuzzle extends GuzzleClient
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct([
            'proxy' => [
                'http' => PROXY_IP,
                'https' => PROXY_IP,
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the only way out of this situation is to use parent class.

```
/**
* 
*/
class ViaProxy implements ConnectViaProxy
{

    public function __construct(GuzzleClient $client)
    {
        // Should be an instance of ProxiedGuzzle
        dd($client);
    }
}
```

Then just use it in cases you need

```
/**
 * 
 */
class FooProvider extends ViaProxy implements Provider
{

}
```

And don't if not

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client as GuzzleClient;
/**
 * 
 */
class BarProvider implements Provider
{
    public function __construct(GuzzleClient $client)
    {
        // Should be an instance of GuzzleClient
        dd($client);
    }
```

use contextual binding as usual

```
$this->app->when(ViaProxy::class)
    ->needs(GuzzleClient::class)
    ->give(function (): ProxiedGuzzle {
        return new ProxiedGuzzle();
    });
```